# Is there a database of original Minifigure configurations, including their personal gear?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

Is there a minifigure museum? I have a gallon jar (& more) of minifigures that my kids have mixed and matched. Is there a website I can reference in order to put the minifigures back in their original configurations (including their gear)?

Comment: Thanks! I'd say you are all correct! I haven't read the book yet, but the websites are great. I'm having a blast.

Comment: I perused the websites & read the book review. Does anyone know if the book shows the accessories that go with each minifig? The links show them bare handed.

Comment: I'm on the waiting list with the KING CO library system. Hoping to have a definitive answer soon.

Comment: Our library has declined to stock the book at this time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The website Brickset.com has an extensive database of sets, digital copies of instructions and a [Minifig database](http://brickset.com/minifigs/browse/) built in cooperation with Bricklink. The layout and style may be a little more user friendly than the Bricklink catalogue and if you register on the site you can keep track of your collection.

Answer (score 9):

The [Unofficial LEGO Minifigure Catalog](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1463518978) lists every minifigure ever produced, up to 2010.

[image: Unofficial LEGO Minifigure Catalog]

Comment: I must admit, however, that I can't comment on the quality nor usefulness of this book for the task in hand, as I have not actually seen a copy myself. Unfortunately, the cover price is just too high for something I wouldn't use that much. Nevertheless, I hope the link to the book will prove useful to  someone else.

Comment: You are right. It is a bit spendy. I imagine it would be an entertaining book to check out at the librairy.

Answer (score 5):

At BrickLink you can browse through, what seams to be, all the existing Minifigures.

This [link](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=M&catString=34) is the query that seams to returns most of them but you will have to dig around in the other Lego themes(categories) to find the other ones.